# Place a TextView next to another TextView for longer text on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

My goal is to have 2 `TextView`s (`textLeft`, `textRight`) next to each other. `textLeft` should be aligned to the left side of parent. `textRight` should always be an immediate right of `textLeft` (not on the extreme right of device), and it should not be pushed out of screen if `textLeft` is too long.

Horizontal `LinearLayout` is of no use here as using weights will fix the view size, and that's not desired.

I have been using this `RelativeLayout` which works fine if `textLeft` is not too long. With longer texts, `textRight` is pushed off screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".TextAlignActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Text On the Left - long random text to follow"
    />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textLeft"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Text on the Right"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I guess ConstraintLayout may be a good fit for such cases, but I am not very familiar. I would like to avoid that if possible, since it will need a heavy re-write of my existing layout.

**EDIT:**

1. In order to simplify my query, I am using 2 `TextView`s in the example. In my app code `textLeft` is a vertical `LinearLayout` with 2 `TextViews` (`textLeftTop` and `textLeftBottom`) instead of a single `TextView` as shown in example. I am hoping the solution that works for 2 `TextViews` should also work for a `LinearLayout` and `TextView`.
2. Based on the solutions so far, I should clarify that I need the `textRight` to be on immediate right of `textLeft` (not device right) if `textLeft` is not long. If `textLeft` is long, then `textRight` should "stick" to the device right, and `textLeft` should wrap text.

Comment: That might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032468/how-to-use-wrap-content-with-a-maximum-width

Comment: @Wonay This thread helped but one key thing missing in the accepted answer is that a fixed margin is applied as a hack on the right child. In my question, I don't know the width of textRight in advance and so can't use a fixed margin on textRight and equivalent padding on textLeft.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

This layout is a kind of "chatting" layout. You can use two `LinearLayout`, one is parent of all with `match_parent`, and the other is holder of two `TextView`s. Note that latter one has `wrap_content` width.

`layout_weight` attribute of `LinearLayout` means... roughly speaking, smaller number is important.

See also: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello world"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="20dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test test test test test test test test "
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello world"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Outdated answer**

Note that `textLeft` has 0dp width.

If you set width (or height) to 0 in constraint layout, it means it will fill rest of the empty space.

Or, you can use `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight` with 0dp width, you can set percentage of width of layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLeft"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/textRight"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!  "
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textLeft"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: textRight doesn't stick to the textLeft if textLeft is small, it's pushed to the right edge of screen leaving a big gap between textLeft and textRight. If textLeft is long, textLeft wraps itself leaving enough room for textRight as desired.

Comment: @Jaguar I edited my answer. Please try my new suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text1ldksjdaskldjadlkjdaslkdjsl"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text2dsjdakldjlkajdlskdjasldkjdlskdjasdlaskdjasldkj"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm not sure if this is what you were asking for, in any case I just checked a few scenarios where the texts are longer in both textviews. 
I also suggest you to convert your layouts to constraint layout, eventually you will benefit from it, you could easily flatten your tree view hierarchy without using too many inner layouts.

Comment: Thanks but this approach does not work if textLeft is small - in which case textRight is placed at extreme right on device, but I need it to be immediate right to textLeft.

Comment: change android:gravity of text2 to left instead of right

Comment: Using gravity left helped a little, but text2 now starts at the middle of the screen - there is still a large gap between text1 and text2 if text1 has short text.

Comment: text2 can start in the middle of the screen because it depends how long is text1, I checked a few scenarios when text1 is shorter than text2 it will next to it. The only gap I noticed is between text2 to the end of the layout (in case text2 has a short text). what scenario did you find when there is a gap between the text1 and text2?

Comment: Looks like we are seeing different outputs. I updated my question a couple hours ago saying that in my app, I am not using text1 on the left, but a vertical LinearLayout with 2 textviews. I used that for simplicity. Do you think that's creating an issue?

Answer (score 0):

**you can implement this code in this way**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Text On the Left - long random text to follow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textLeft"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Text on the Right"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"  />
```

**or that one**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Text On the Left - long random text to follow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textLeft"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Text on the Right"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textLeft"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
```

Comment: `android:layout_toEndOf` is valid for RelativeLayout only. do you mean `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf`?