# Android-Layout: Place two TextViews in a row and adjust the size of the second TextView based on the size of the first

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a **CardView** layout which I feed to the **RecyclerView**. There are Six (6) **TextView**s, with Two (2) **TextView**s per row. The **TextView**s on the left are titles while the ones on the right are values that are drawn from a database.

I want the width of the titles to match the width of the longest title, and the values fill the rest of the space inside the **CardView** like this:

[image]

*In this example, the Subject is the longest word and so the rest of the titles match the width of the Subject*

I tried to use ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:focusable="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/to"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/to"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/from"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/from"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/to"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subjectLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/subject"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/subject"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/from" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo, it's summertime. It's rainy though mate. Let's hangout at Macy's later."
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/subjectLabelTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/subjectLabelTextView" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The problem here is that when the text is too long, the value of the right TextView is being pushed out of the screen.

So I tried the nested Linear Layout as shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55251997/7764977

with the following code:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello world"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="20dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="test test test test test test test test "
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello world"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is almost perfect. However, each row is housed in different LinearLayout. So I cannot get one title to match the width of the longest title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Barrier` for such arrangement. So all 3 Title `TextViews` will be  constraints start of the `Barrier` and all 3 content `TextViews` will be  constraints end of the `Barrier`. So any of left TextView Grow in width it will push content `TextViews` towards end .. Try the following layout:-

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:focusable="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/to"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="To"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="From"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toContent" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subjectLabelTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Subject"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fromContent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
                android:id="@+id/barrier"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:barrierDirection="end"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="to,subjectLabelTextView,from"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="395dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subject"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yo, it's summertime. It's rainy though mate. Let's hangout at Macy's later."
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/subjectLabelTextView" />


        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toContent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Me ertime. It's rainy though mate. Let's hangouMacy'"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/to" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fromContent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="it's me"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/from" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```