# Why my TextView invisible with long text in previous TextView in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, position, android-linearlayout

I have this XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView            
            style="@style/Icon"
            tools:background="@color/Black54Opacity" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView                    
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"                                        
                    android:ellipsize="end"                    
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"                    
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    tools:text="LONG LONG LONG" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"                    
                    android:minWidth="18dp"
                    tools:text="2342"
                    tools:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView                
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:textColor="4CAF50"
                tools:text="EDIT" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

When I insert a short text in my first TextView - I haven't a problem.
[image: Short text]
[image: Long text]

When I insert a long text in my first textView - my second TextView moved under the third TextView.
[image: Very Very long text]

I want the text in the first TextView can resize to that point so that the other two TextViews don't change their size.

The long text in the first TextView was ellipsized in the end.
The second TextView must always be pressed against the left side of the first TextView.

Comment: can you show me your XML layout screen ?

Comment: @Niceumang I updated my question with pictures.

Comment: @Sergey Try to add weight to your second TextView

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199856/5805371

Comment: The weight didn't help me, because I must not change the width for the second TextView. And second TextView must bound to the right side of first TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution through the `ConstraintLayout`.

1. We remove all `LinearLayout`.
2. Then we added `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` in my first TextView. It's a very important attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use weight to your TextView

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
 android:id="@+id/img"/>

<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:weightSum="5"
 android:orientation="horizontal">


<TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="2"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="2" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="Edit"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I use weight my text in second TextView didn't bound to the left side of first TextView. Screenshot: http://joxi.ru/GrqyyNMC4zjJxr

Comment: please share your xml

Comment: you can also remove weight of second TextView, set width and height on wrap

Comment: It doesn't help. My second TextView didn't bound to the right side of first TextView again...