# TextView overlaps with another textview

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-linearlayout

I want the text to be displayed to the right of the name,but if the name is too large, the text on the right doesn't fit on the screen. I used the following solution, but it causes the first textview to stretch beyond the size of the text in it.

What I have:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7797.png)

What I want:
[concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0fMu.png)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/readed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_new"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:paddingHorizontal="5dp"
            android:paddingVertical="3dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="554"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove android:weighSum="1" and android:layout_weight attribute in two textViews

```
enter code here<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/readed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_new"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:paddingHorizontal="5dp"
        android:paddingVertical="3dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="554"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does not work. If string is too long(in "label"), "label" overlays "readed"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032468/how-to-use-wrap-content-with-a-maximum-width/48199856 this will be solved your problem